# Optimise looping through file contents

Tags: powershell, text-processing

I have two files, `file1` and `file2`. I need to check if all the contents in `file1` are present in `file2`.
Contents of the `file1` will be as following:

```
ABC1234
BFD7890
```

And contents of `file2` will be as following:

```
ABC1234_20180902_XYZ
BFD7890_20110890_123
```

They will not be in any specific order, and it is not possible to split by delimiter, as they are different in different lines. Only thing I need to confirm is that if string from `file1` is present in some part of `file2`. There will not be two occurrence of the same pattern.

Both files contains more than 20000 lines.

This is what I currently have:

```
$filesfromDB   = gc file1.txt
$filesfromSFTP = gc file2.txt
foreach ($f in $filesfromDB) {
    $FilePresentStatus = $filesfromSFTP | Select-String -Quiet -Pattern $f
    if ($FilePresentStatus -ne $true) {
        $MissingFiles += $f
    }
}
```

This works fine if the files are small, but when I run this in prod, it is really slow. It takes around 4 hours to complete this loop. How do I optimize this piece of script?

Comment: What are limitations here (line length, charset, anything)? Less specific question means less opportunities to optimize.

Comment: @PetSerAl, sorry I dont understand your query.

Comment: Unless a delimiter could be **ANY** character, "*Different delimiters*" doesn't automatically mean you can't use them to split the lines. You might e.g. split a line on any character that is not a word character (e.g.`-Split '\W'`). Besides, if it could be **ANY**, it would mean that a line like `ZABC12345_etc` would also match the example... As @PetSerAl already pointed out, optimizing your script probably lies in refining your definition as (regex) string matching is very expensive. If my assuming is correct; split all lines, put the items in a (very fast) hashtable and do a `ContainsKey()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20000 is not that much, but at worst you have to do 20000x20000=400000000 operations. The key is to stop as soon as possible in each. You can also use much faster `[string].Contains` method instead of regular expression based `Select-String` (unless -SimpleMatch switch is used).

See following demo:

```
$db =   1000000..1020000
$sftp = (1001000..1021000 | % { "$($_)_SomeNotImportantTextHere" }) -join "`r`n"

$missingFiles = $db | where { !$sftp.Contains($_) }
```

Each collection contains 20000 items, 19000 common, 1000 exists only in `$db`. It runs in couple of seconds.

To read `$filesfromSFTP` as one big string, use:

```
gc file2.txt -Raw
```

To convert result to single string, use `$missingFiles -join 'separator'`.

Comment: This is awesome. I had to use `gc file2.txt | Out-string` since i am on powershell 2.0, but changing to this way basically reduced the time to few seconds from hours. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the += operator, try this
https://powershell.org/2013/09/16/powershell-performance-the-operator-and-when-to-avoid-it/

Comment: I doubt if that is the issue, because when I run it, the missing files are only around 300 out of 20000. So at most the array was updated 300 times only. But I will change it to the way you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a hashtable, the code below takes around 15 minutes on my laptop with 2 files containing 20000 lines.

```
$filesfromDB   = gc file1.txt
$filesfromSFTP = gc file2.txt
$MissingFiles  = @()
$hashtbl       = @{}

foreach ($f in $filesfromDB) {
    $hashtbl."Line$($f.ReadCount)"=[regex]$f
}

foreach ($key in $hashtbl.Keys) {
    $FilePresentStatus = $hashtbl[$key].Matches($filesfromSFTP)
    if ($FilePresentStatus.Count -eq 0) {
        $MissingFiles += $hashtbl[$key].ToString()
    }
}
```